# Sublime build scrambles Gradle build output

Tags: java, gradle, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am running a gradle Java build using sublime text build system. I am using Linux Mint 19.1.

When I run the build command (gradlew build) from sublime text,  output is is being scrambled. When running the same build from the terminal, the output is as expected. In sublime the first characters of the output "> Task" are gone, and the first instance of the word "FAILED" plus the following newline, are moved a few lines down.

**In Terminal**

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
/home/me/mycode/src/main/java/CLIClient.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
sfpublic class CLIClient {
^
1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

**In Sublime**

```
:compileJava/home/me/mycode/src/main/java/CLIClient.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
sfpublic class CLIClient {
^
1 error
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

My Sublime build system is defined as follows...

```
{
    "cmd": ["./gradlew" , "build"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path}",
    "file_regex": "^(/...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)"
}
```

Comment: Is gradle trying to display colored output or doing incremental display (like displaying a line, then jumping the cursor back to the start and outputting something different on the same line)?

Answer (score 0):

By default, gradle does a bit of command line magic where it shows the progress of the current task fixed on the screen. It also displays colours. I'm guessing this is not compatible with sublime text.

You can switch this off by passing `--console=plain` on the gradle command line

I'm guessing that would mean

```
{
    "cmd": ["./gradlew" , "build", "--console=plain"],
    "working_dir": "${project_path}",
    "file_regex": "^(/...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)"
}
```

Comment: using --console=plain from the command line works to remove color. But when using it in the sublime build, the same problem persists....

Comment: Can you explain exactly what's wrong? In the console I believe that "1 actionable task: 1 executed" is remaining at the bottom of the screen via the magic I mentioned earlier. Try adding `--console=plain` at command line and you should see the same as sublime where text is shown in the order it occurs in the build. Perhaps its an issue with multiple threads, in which case you can tell gradle to use a single thread/daemon